# How can I parse dynamic content from a web page?

Tags: java, javascript, html-parsing, jsoup, dynamic-data

I try to get a proxy list from this url:

[Free proxy list](http://spys.ru/en/free-proxy-list/)

This would be cool, but port number is dynamic JavaScript content. How can I get JavaScript-generated content from this page? I have jsoup and djNativeSwing but I want do this in background thread.

```
JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.navigate("http://spys.ru/en/free-proxy-list/");
System.out.println(webBrowser.getHTMLContent());
```

this code returns a Null result. Help please.

Comment: check out `htmlUnit` I think it is the one thing that you need. Thanks.

Comment: i think this is not for me. My code must be simple and crossplatform. As i know HTMLUnit - must have SYSTEM path - it's trouble

Comment: No you do not need system path. I created web crawler using HTMLUnit which works on http protocol. so yes it does work properly. Let me know if you want more help. I can write a formal answer if you want.

Comment: Ohhh! Give me example! I try to use this!

Comment: I'm try to use this code: final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://spys.ru/free-proxy-list1/RU/");
        System.out.println(page.toString());

Comment: And get this error: Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider
 at sinonimizer.PGinside.getProxyInfo(PGinside.java:60)
 at sinonimizer.PGinside.run(PGinside.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadCla

Comment: What is this? All libs added in project...

Comment: htmlunit lib, 5 commons, cssparser lib... anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The webbrowser hasn't finnished loading when you call the getHtmlContent() method. Use something like this instead:

```
JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.navigate("http://spys.ru/en/free-proxy-list/");
webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserListener(){
   public void loadingProgressChanged(WebBrowserEvent e){
       if(e.getWebBrowser().getLoadingProgress()==100)
            System.out.println(webBrowser.getHTMLContent());
   }
}
/* Note: I wrote this in the comment field without any testing,
   you probably have to make the webBrowser final. */
```

[JavaDocs](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html) is your friend!

Comment: Thanks for fast replay, but i nothig to get from this code. And how to   not building all abstrcat class for event.

Comment: 2 secs, I'll try to get the lib and test it out

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with the library. Even if I use a timer to wait for a long period of time, webBrowser.getHTMLContent() returns null for some reason

Comment: Do yo have any ideas? I'm try to use this example to and so it is