# Parsing only text content from url

Tags: php

I am trying to parse text content from url given. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097352/how-can-i-parse-dynamic-content-from-a-web-page';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;                          // This parse everything on the page, including image + everything

$text=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($content));
echo "</br>";
echo $text;   // This gives source code also, not only the text content over page
?>
```

I want to get only the text written over page. No page source code. Any idea for this? I already googled but above method only present everywhere.

Comment: http://php.net/strip-tags

Comment: For what reason you are using `escapeshellarg`?

Comment: @CORRUPT: I have already used it. It also gives source code. Not only the text written on page.

Comment: I am passing entire content as a argument to c++ program. `escapeshellarg` quote the result by  `''` so that it can be encountered as single argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode
```

Instead of using xpath, you can also do:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url); // Load the HTML
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) { // for all scripts
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script); // remove script and content 
                                               // so it will not appear in text
}
$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode, get the text.
```

Comment: thanks but still we get ` "https:") { p += "s"; d = "engine"; } var z = document.createElement("script"); z.type = "text/javascript"; z.async = true; z.src = p + "://" + d + ".adzerk.net/ados.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s); var ados = ados || {}; ados.run = ados.run || []; ados.run.push(function () { ados_setKeywords('java,javascript,html-parsing,jsoup,dynamic-data');; ados_load(); }); var _gaq=_gaq||`  etc etc

Comment: @Karimkhan It is text content of `<script>` tag. If you do not want it, you have to manually remove it, with `XPath` for example. See edited answer. Depending on site, you may have to also remove other unwanted tags.

Comment: I have to keep it generalized, because user may enter any url!

Comment: @jaudette: Why it gives bunch of warnings? 
` arning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097352/how-can-i-parse-dynamic-content-from-a-web-page, line: 255 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/test.php on line 13

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097352/how-can-i-parse-dynamic-content-from-a-web-page, line: 255 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/test.php on line 13

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in htt ` etc etc

Comment: @Karimkhan Is it the same warnings for every url, or specific to your page? What is on line 13? According to doc: `While malformed HTML should load successfully, this function may generate E_WARNING errors when it encounters bad markup. libxml's error handling functions may be used to handle these errors.`

Comment: Those warning got removed by 'libxml_use_internal_errors(true);' see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943954/removing-docdocument-warnigng-while-parsing-page-content

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = file_get_contents(strip_tags($url));
```

This will remove the HTML tags coming form the page

Answer (score 1):

To remove html tag use:

```
$text = strip_tags($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple **`cURL`** will solve the issue. **[TESTED]**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097352/how-can-i-parse-dynamic-content-from-a-web-page");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //Sorry forgot to add this
echo strip_tags(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: thanks but still it gives code like `  $('#tell-me-more').click(function () { var clickSource = $("body").attr("class") + '-mini'; if ($("body").hasClass("questions-page")) { clickSource = 'questionpagemini'; } if ($("body").hasClass("home-page")) { clickSource = 'homepagemini'; } StackExchange.using("gps", function () { StackExchange.gps.track("aboutpage.click", { aboutclick_location: clickSource } , `   etc. Which should not come

Comment: You need to do a lot of parsing to get the data. Before that you need to get permission from SO as you are using their resources without using any API as this is synonymous to 'Leeching'

Comment: its not only about so, any url can be there!