# How to get links of text from an html page?

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I want to get the links "http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp" & "http://www.google.com" from this webpage.I want the links of `<a>` tags inside `<div class="link">`,there are many other `<a>` tags in this page and I don't want them. How can I retrieve the particular links only? Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="link">
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp">
<h4>W3 Schools</h4>
</a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<h4>Google</h4>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720805/php-regular-expression-to-get-a-url-from-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a DOM Parser such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/dom) to achieve this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // $html is a string containing the HTML

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp
http://www.google.com
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80922)

---

**UPDATE:** If you only want the links inside the specific `<div>`, you can use an [XPath](http://php.net/xpath) expression to find the links inside the div, and then loop through them to get the `href` attribute:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links_inside_div = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'link')]/a");

foreach ($links_inside_div as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br/>';
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80945)

Comment: I want to get only those <a> tag links inside <div class="link"> Note:There are many other <a href=""> tags are there

Comment: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 38 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fetch\bkadafetch.php on line 7`    This is the output when I executed the code, line 7 contains `$dom->loadHTML($html);`

Comment: Although, it's not considered a very good practice, you can use `@$dom->loadHTML($html);` to suppress the warnings. A better idea might be to use `libxml_internal_errors()`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18943981/1438393).

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
  echo $node->nodeValue.': '.$node->getAttribute("href")."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use snoopy PHP class . Snoopy is a PHP class that simulates a web browser. It automates the task of retrieving web page content and posting forms,   http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/

Otherwise try to using Jquery

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $( ".link a" ).each(function( index ) {
             var link = $( this ).attr("href") );
             alert(link );
         });
    });
</script>
```

You can also get all links using this one also (javascript)

```
 var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```